# Android webapp rotation bug

Tags: jquery, android, css

Android 2.3.4
Tablet: HTC Flyer
Application: Webapp, HTML, Jquery Mobile, CSS

Hello, 
I've created an webapp which features a grill with different applications (the webapp its simialr to an Android Market) but features only my applications.

After rotating the tablet a few times, the whole page zooms about 5px per image. This includes the navigation bar, logo, applications logos, menu, everything. Basically the whole page gets zoomed in. Therefore, all my images are squeezed in due to CSS.

What causes this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it get zoomed in everytime you rotate it? Or just after a few times? Can you post some code? Like for example, where you handle the rotation or where you create your view.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices, such as the iPad do this by default. You should first check to see if this zoom happens on other sites. If not, then check CSS media queries (if you have any), or make sure you aren't accidentally zooming with your fingers.

This meta tag will come in handy if you don't want the user scrolling btw:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```